# Using Maven to build Storm project but cannot find the resulted java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, apache-storm

I got the following output after doing command "mvn eclipse:eclipse".
It showed that the build is successful but no java project was built there. 
I could not figure out why.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for storm.cookbook:hello-world:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 105, column 9
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hello-world 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) @ hello-world >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) @ hello-world <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) @ hello-world ---
[INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: null
[INFO] Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER
[INFO] Wrote settings to /home/junfu/RESEARCH/HelloWorld/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
[INFO] Wrote Eclipse project for "hello-world" to /home/junfu/RESEARCH/HelloWorld.
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.896 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-30T15:55:26-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So you are saying that the `/home/junfu/RESEARCH/HelloWorld` directory doesn't exist?

Comment: Additionally, `eclipse:eclipse` is obsolete. Use m2eclipse instead and import the project from within Eclipse.

Comment: No, I created that directory, but I assume there should be some java code generated after the build right? But no java code is generated so when I write code, it cannot find the classes such as "Tuple" or "BaseRichBolt".